# Amazon QLDB Multi-Region Architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-qldb

I am new to QLDB and seem to be finding slightly conflicting info on multi-Region architecture. I see that it has high availability in a given Region; however, it is unclear as to what happens when an entire Region goes down, or how I use it in a hot-hot multi-Region application.

Let's assume that an application is in US-East-2 and US-West-2 with latency routing rules. Each of these needs to write and read from the same ledger. Is this possible, or would the ledger need to exist in a single region and only one region can have full-access while the other would only have access to a read-only copy (maybe in S3)?

Comment: There is no multi-region active-active configuration for QLDB, it's just not a supported feature.

Comment: This is kind of what I was expecting. So, essentially, Region down == app down (assuming this is a critical component).

Comment: Yes, although to be fair - "Region down" hasn't happened in 15 years afaik. (That does **not** mean it won't ever happen, just that AWS tends to be pretty good at running their infrastructure)

Comment: Fair point.  Thanks for the information, Maurice.  :)

Answer (score 0):

As of 21/6/2021 QLDB ledgers are in a single region. Cross-region business continuity is a need we have heard from other customers and we take this feedback very seriously. I will come back to this answer in the future when there is an update.

Comment: Thanks for this. Curious how the recent issue with the load balancers in US-East-2 would have affected access to QLDB in that region?